# Understanding legacy Python one-liner that now gives error

Tags: python

```
cats = CatService.find_all()
data['value'] = [cat for cat in cats if cat.label == data['value']][0].name
```

I am unable to understand what this line written in Python is doing. It used to work, but now I am getting a `list index out of range` error.

`cats[0].name` gave results and was not `null` before running the above statement, but still I got the error.

The legacy code is written in  aone-liner as above. When I got the error I had to dissect it as below.

I tried to write the code in this format to analyze and debug. But then I don't get the error. I suppose this is not the right translation of the one-liner:

```
for cat in cats:
    if cat.label == data['value']:
        print("cat match is " + cat.label)
        data['value'] = cats[0].name
    else:
        print("cat non-match is " + cat.label)
```

Comment: A really easy way to figure out what a one-liner does is to start removing parts from the outside in and see what the result is. In other words, start by removing the `.name`, then the `[0]`, etc. If I had to guess, there are no items that match the condition in the list comprehension, which is causing your out of range error.

Comment: Can you add line where `cats` is defined?

Comment: `[0]` applies to the first cat whose label matches `data['value']`, the unfiltered list of `cats` as in your conversion.

Comment: done. the service is going 'cat.objects.all()' return

Comment: The list comprehension is bit of a waste, because you don't care about any cat other than the first one in the list.

Comment: exactly. So why are we looping past the first match ? That is confusing me

Comment: @chepner Not true, if any of the cats match then it is set to a value from the first cat.

Comment: You wouldn't; you'd use `break` one you processed the first match.

Comment: is 'break' part of the oneliner?

Comment: @chepner If `cats[1].label == data['value']` then the `if` statement evaluates to `True` on the second iteration, even if it evaluated to `False` on the first one

Comment: Yes, but the list so constructed is then indexed with `[0]` immediately; no other cats will have their `name` attribute used.

Comment: @chepner There is no list that is constructed in the question

Comment: @ErikMcKelvey I'm talking about the list comprehension in the original code, not the OP's attempt to convert it to a `for` loop.

Comment: @chepner Oh I get it now. I thought he wanted to convert the code into a one liner not the other way around

Comment: No, the  legacy code is written in oneliner. When I got the error I had to dissect it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I feel that both existing answers here are already good, but I'm going to see if I can break this down even more explicitly. First of all, I recommend reading [this article](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/) that gives a very nice explanation of list comprehensions and how to see what they're equivalent to in for loops.

So, here's the original one-liner:

```
data['value'] = [cat for cat in cats if cat.label == data['value']][0].name
```

Your for loop version is not doing quite the same thing. Most notably, you're grabbing `cats[0]`, the first item in the *original list*, not the list built by the list comprehension. Let's expand the original one-liner one step at a time. First, we'll assign the list comprehension to a variable for a little clarity:

```
matching_cats = [cat for cat in cats if cat.label == data['value']]
data['value'] = matching_cats[0].name
```

As you can see, `data['value']` ends up pointing to the name of the first cat *in the list of matching cats*. This is where you're getting your error: for whatever reason, no cats match your condition, so `matching_cats` is an empty list, `[]`, and thus there *is* no first element, `matching_cats[0]`.

Now, if we expand the list comprehension to a for loop:

```
matching_cats = []
for cat in cats:
    if cat.label == data['value']:
        matching_cats.append(cat)
data['value'] = matching_cats[0].name
```

This is an entirely literal translation of the original code, and should get the same error when using the same data. Again, it builds a list of all cats that match the condition, then sets `data['value']` to the name of the first match that was found.

As pointed out in both [chepner's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70336763/12975140) and [Chen A.'s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70336702/12975140) answers, there are two problems with this code:

1. As you've found, it crashes if no cats match the condition.
2. Even if it finds one cat that matches, it then keeps checking all the rest of the cats, even though ultimately you only want one. That's a waste!

Because of this, I'd recommend using the alternative code presented in either of those answers, ending iteration early as soon as a match is found (and being prepared in case there is no match).

Answer (score 2):

The error you encounter is pretty self explanatory; *it means there are no items in the list you're accessing.*

You're updating `data['value']` with the result of list-comprehension `[cat for cat in cats if cat.label == data['value']][0].name`. Notice you relay on `[0]` element in the returned list. When the list is empty, you'll encounter this error.

You can't really extract a value from list-comprehension, as it may have 0 elements. You gotta run it in a for loop,

```
for cat in cats:
  if cat.label == data['value']:
    data['value'] = cat.name
    break
```

Note that you probably want to break after a match.

---

If you break down your updated code,

```
data['value'] = [cat for cat in cats if cat.label == data['value']][0].name
```

This compares every `cat` in `cats`, and creats a list of all matching cats (which would be the same since you compare `cat.label == data['value']`. So you might end up with 0, 1, or N cats in the list.

You then take the first item's name: `[<RESULT CAT LIST OF N CATS>][0].name`. The code doesn't care about the rest of the items in that list. *So why create it in the first place?*

The code snippet above does what the code intent to do; find the first matching cat and returns it's name.

Comment: the list in not empty and still get the error. I tried checks before entering the oneliner

Comment: also in your solution we are not taking the '0' value

Comment: The 0 value is the first match, which is what the for loop does as it *breaks* after the first match. There's no other reason for `index out of range` to be thrown besides accessing a non-existent element in the array; if element 0 doesn't exist - it means it's empty

Comment: cats[0].name as checked for non-null so that cannot be the error. And yes it is a mystery why we get the error

Comment: Your updated code seems different. You now iterate the cats array, and if there's a match of `cat.label == data['value']` you take the *first item in cats*, not the one that matched.

Comment: that is what the onliner is doing right? taking the first item of the array?

Comment: Yes. I've updated the answer to add an example

Comment: What is the purpose of '[0].name' in the one liner?

Comment: Your answer is questioning the existence or purpose of legacy code. But that is not this question is about I am afraid.

Comment: Like Chen A. said... `[cat for cat in cats if cat.label == data['value']]` is a list comprehension. It builds a list of all cats that match the condition. `[0]` gets the first item of that list (assuming there is one). `.name` then gets that cat's name. When no cats match the condition, the list comprehension builds an empty list, and `[0]` throws an `IndexError`.

Comment: @BlueClouds when you encounter such legacy code, consider refactoring it. Will make your future self life easier.

Comment: of course that is the goal

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't have used the list comprehension in the first place, as you don't want a list of matching cats; you only want the *first* matching cat. I would have written

```
cats = CatService.find_all()
for cat in cats:
    if cat.label == data['value']:
        data['value'] = cat.name
        break
```

A similar alternative to the loop might be

```
if any((found:=cat).label == data['value'] for cat in cats):
    data['value'] = found.name
```

`any` short-circuits, so if a matching cat is found, `found` will be bound to the object that matched. If no match is found, `any` returns `False` and the object that `found` is bound to (i.e., the last cat in the list) isn't relevant or used.

I leave it to each reader to decide for themselves which is more readable. They should be comparable in performance.

Comment: In the question `data['value']` gets set to `cats[0].name`

Comment: No, it doesn't, if `cats[0].label` doesn't match the current value of `data['value']`.

Comment: in the onliner what is the '0' for?

Comment: It's a list index. The list being indexed just isn't bound to a name first; it's the list comprehension being indexed directly. `[...][0]` is the same as `foo = [...]; foo[0]`.

Comment: Or `next((cat.name for cat in cats if cat.label == data['vale']), data['value'])`

Comment: Yeah, but I prefer the explicit loop that avoids the no-op reassignment of `data['value']` to `data['value']` if no matching cat is found.